# Why is 403 error being thrown?

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have a webservice (implemented in spring java) that's running in a my local machine.
Now I can use rest client(Firefox plugin) to invoke webservice from my own machine however when I am trying to access the webservice from another machine the server is throwing  HTTP 403 error! I have disabled firewall in my local machine still the same forbidden error is being thrown. What could possibly be the reason?

Comment: HTTP 403 means that your webservice can be reached (because it responds with a HTTP 403 error). The webservice determined that what you were trying to do is forbidden. Check your webservice logs what is going on.

Comment: Do you access your Webservice using HTTPS? Because in that case you may need to add the servers certificate to your clients truststore

Comment: You have answer in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166667/how-to-handle-cross-domain-web-service-calls-from-js-in-orchard-cms. Other technology, but same problem.

Comment: No I am not using HTTPS .It seems like the request is not coming upto my server!

Comment: What is in the web service log files?