# How to access web service from Javascript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, curl

I want to access a web service from [here](http://services.tropicos.org/) in my web application. When the user chooses a species name, the service will inform if the name is valid, the author and year of the name, etc.

First I thought of using Javascript, since the information comes from the user. Then I saw [cross-domain restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), so I wonder what is the best workaround here. According to [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169277/1086511), I should be using a server-side workaround. But in that case, wouldn't it be easier to just use [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php) functions?

Comment: Yes...!?! Using PHP curl (or similar) is what "server-side workaround" refers to...!? Unclear what your question is.

Comment: The server-side workaround probably is the same as using PHP curl functions.

Comment: @deceze In the link I show PHP curl is not the workaround suggested. Thus my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you want to do this reliably, do it from a computer you control.

If you are using PHP already, than cURL is the usual HTTP client library.

That said, using PHP/cURL on your server **is** the server side workaround to cross-origin JS issues, not an alternative to using a workaround.

Answer (score -2):

Try this ajax code.

```
 $.ajax({   

        url: 'http://localhost/webservice.php?callback=',

        type: "GET/POST",

        data:{data:JSON.stringify([{action:'getUserData', userId: 1234}])},

        dataType: "jsonp",

        crossdomain: true
 });
```

For more details refer this link [HTML-PHP Webservice](http://sanjaykumarns.blogspot.in/p/html-php-webservice-jquery-ajax.html) using the AJAX with crossDomain as TRUE.

Comment: $.ajax supposes I'm using jquery? I'm not. When we talk about javascript, no framework should be supposed as "obvious".